# disable webapp scrolling without killing click (tap) events in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, scroll, touch

This is my first post so ill try to explain it clear:

Im working on a web application, but the main point is, that i want let my users feel like its a native app. In a native app you cant scroll like in iOS safari so i tried to disable scrolling with event.preventDefault. This works great except that form elements and links arent tapable anymore. My solution to that was this little script, but if you start a touch on one of the escaped elements, it scrolls anyway. Not a big deal but its driving me insane...

notes to script:
isTouch returns true/false if its a touchable device
the .contains method returns true/false if an array contains a string

```
if (isTouch) {
    window.addEventListener("touchstart", function (evt) {
        var target = evt.touches[0].target;
        var tags = 'a input textarea button'.split(' ');

        if ( tags.contains(target.tagName) === false ) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }       
    }, false);
}
```

**EDIT**
My main question is, is there a solution to fire the tap event without a touchmove event to allow scrolling

**EDIT 2**
I solved the problem. My solution is, to emulate the events on interactive elements:

```
var eventFire = function (el, etype) {
    if (el.fireEvent) {
        (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
    }
    else {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
        evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
}

if (isTouch) {
    window.addEventListener("touchstart", function (evt) {
        var target = evt.touches[0].target;
        var foc = 'input textarea'.split(' ');
        var clck = 'a button'.split(' ');

        if ( foc.contains(target.tagName) ) {
            target.focus();
            eventFire(target,'click');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }

    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this code on Safari browsers ?

Comment: I have tested this on ios safari on my ipad, and it works great, like i said except that it scrolls anyway if i start a touch on one of the escaped elements (a, input, button...)